# "Controlvault firmware upgrade finished Restart computer" at every power-up

Tags: windows-7, reboot

Windows 7, Dell Latitude computer, new hard drive, new Windows install.

After every power-up (reboot) the taskbar shows:

> Controlvault firmware upgrade finished Restart computer

and disappears before I can reach the notice.

What does it mean? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Thats the fingerprint reader software, try reinstalling it or remove it if you do not use the FR.....https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=Controlvault+firmware+upgrade+finished+Restart+computer&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english

Comment: @Moab: I doesn't appear so, or, at least, it appears to be more than that: "Dell™ ControlVault™, ... provides a hardened and secure bank for storing and processing user credentials. ControlVault keeps passwords, biometric templates, and security codes within firmware and locked away from a malicious application attack. ... by isolating them from the Windows environment and memory, which is notoriously unsecure. Instead, all processing and storage of critical data takes place on a processing and memory chip — providing a protective and secure boundary."

Answer (score 0):

My computer repair person tell me the problem is that ControlVault is a 16-bit version, and the computer is 64-bits. He fixed it by going to the DeviceManager and disabling the service.